# Helm Grafana/Loki chart installation error. Rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, grafana, grafana-loki

I need to install Grafana Loki with Prometheus in my Kubernetes cluster. So I followed the below to install them. It basically uses Helm to install it. Below is the command which I executed to install it.

```
helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack  --set grafana.enabled=true,prometheus.enabled=true,prometheus.alertmanager.persistentVolume.enabled=false,prometheus.server.persistentVolume.enabled=false,loki.persistence.enabled=true,loki.persistence.storageClassName=standard,loki.persistence.size=5Gi -n monitoring --create-namespace
```

I followed the [official Grafana website](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/installation/helm/) in this case.

But when I execute the above helm command, I get the below error. In fact, I'm new to Helm.

```
Release "loki" does not exist. Installing it now.
W0307 16:54:55.764184 1474330 warnings.go:70] policy/v1beta1 PodSecurityPolicy is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: PodSecurityPolicy "loki-grafana" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "loki": current value is "loki-grafana"
```

I don't see any Grafana chart installed.

```
helm list -A
NAME            NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION
cert-manager    cert-manager    1               2021-11-26 13:07:26.103036078 +0000 UTC deployed        cert-manager-v0.16.1    v0.16.1
ingress-nginx   ingress-basic   1               2021-11-18 12:23:28.476712359 +0000 UTC deployed        ingress-nginx-4.0.8     1.0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was able to get through my issue. The issue was "PodSecurityPolicy". I deleted the existing Grafana PodSecurityPolicy and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```yaml
rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: PodSecurityPolicy "loki-grafana" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "loki": current value is "loki-grafana"
```

Deleting `PodSecurityPolicy` could be a solution, but better you can change annotation key `meta.helm.sh/release-name` from `loki-grafana` to `loki`.

Additionally I can see you are using deprecated API:

```yaml
policy/v1beta1 PodSecurityPolicy is deprecated in v1.21+, unavailable in v1.25+
```

To solve it look at [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/deprecation-guide/#poddisruptionbudget-v125):

> The  **policy/v1beta1**  API version of PodDisruptionBudget will no longer be served in v1.25.
>
> - Migrate manifests and API clients to use the  **policy/v1**  API version, available since v1.21.
> - All existing persisted objects are accessible via the new API
> - Notable changes in  **policy/v1**:
>   -   an empty  `spec.selector`  (`{}`) written to a  `policy/v1`  PodDisruptionBudget selects all pods in the namespace (in  `policy/v1beta1`  an empty  `spec.selector`  selected no pods). An unset  `spec.selector`  selects no pods in either API version.
>
> ##### PodSecurityPolicy
>
> PodSecurityPolicy in the  **policy/v1beta1**  API version will no longer be served in v1.25, and the PodSecurityPolicy admission controller will be removed.
>
> PodSecurityPolicy replacements are still under discussion, but current use can be migrated to  [3rd-party admission webhooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/)  now.

See also [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) for more information about Dynamic Admission Control.

Answer (score 0):

try this to get all releases in all namespaces, use --all-namespaces flag with helm ls.

Answer (score 0):

Use a version superior tthe 2.10. WOrk for me this 2.16.0